# action_send is worked...javamailapi is not worked in android sendmail function

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I have develop one send email android application.

Here i have to send the more than one product detail is send to email.

I have used below code:

```
  public class InvoiceOrder extends Activity {


        String mGrandTotal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invoice);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    //String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("orderid");
    mGrandTotal = b.getString("GrandTotal");

    ListView mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    CustomerAdapter mViewCartAdpt = new CustomerAdapter(
            InvoiceOrder.this);
    mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);

            Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("krishnaveniv96@gmail.com","arirajaguru");
                    }
                });

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veeman@mercuryminds.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                message.setSentDate(new Date());

                StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
                body.append("<html><body><table>"); 
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail
                        .size(); i++) {

                    String title = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_PNAME);

                    String qty = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_QTY);

                    String cost = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_PRICE);

                    String total = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL);

                    body.append("<tr>" + "<td>" + title
                            + "</td><td>" + qty + " * " + cost
                            + "</td>" + " = <td>" + total
                            + "  " + "</td></tr>");
                }

                body.append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "Grand Total is:-  "
                        + "</td><td>" + mGrandTotal + " "
                    + "</td></tr>");
                body.append("</table></body></html>"); 
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                emailIntent
                        .putExtra(
                                Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                                new String[] { "mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com,krishnaveni.veeman@mercuryminds.com" });

                emailIntent.putExtra(
                        android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                        "Email:")); 
                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
           }



  });
        }

}
```

Here the morethan one product is send to email is successfully done using ACTION_SEND in android application.

But i have to send the more than one product detail to email using java mail api.

i have used javamail api means the single product detail only send to mail...but i have to send mail more than one product detail.

These is my code:

```
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail
                        .size(); i++) {

                    String title = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_PNAME);

                    String qty = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_QTY);

                    String cost = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i)
                            .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_PRICE);

                    String total = Constants.mItem_Detail
                            .get(i).get(
                                    SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL);
                    messageBodyPart.setText(title + qty + cost + total);

                }
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

                 Transport.send(message);
```

whats wrong in my code.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the output after use stringbuffer and append .

```
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();    
                sb.append("<html><body><table>");
```

in for loop :

```
                    StringBuffer buffer = sb.append("<tr>" + "<td>" + title
                            + "</td><td>" + qty + " * " + cost
                            + "</td>" + " = <td>" + total
                            + "  " + "</td></tr>");
                    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler( new ByteArrayDataSource(buffer.toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8")));
```